# How do I get randomness in command-line?

Tags: command-line

How to randomly execute one command within specified list of command? Helpful for randomly choosing startup sound, wallpaper or executing commands.

In General, if I have commands for execution as follows then How do I get randomness:?

```
#!/bin/bash
<command_1>
<command_2>
<command_3>
.
.
.
<command_n>
```

Then I want to **execute randomly only one command** from above possibilities when script is run!

How to do that?

Comment: Practical example: http://askubuntu.com/a/257471/163331

Comment: @Parto I already added as [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/492586/256099) before

Comment: I was not trying to answer, was just giving an example where it can be used.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The variable `$RANDOM` (actually a bash function) returns a random number from 0 to 32767 inclusive.

You would typically want to limit its range by dividing it by some number and take its remainder, eg.

```
# output a random number 0 to 3
echo $((RANDOM % 4))
```

In this simplistic example it'll be very slightly biased for any divisor that doesn't divide equally into 32768 (eg, anything that isn't a power of two), but in your scenario I don't think you'd be troubled by a slight bias.

To pick a random file, you'd name your files something like:

```
file0.jpg
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
```

And then you can pick a random one with

```
# output a random file from file0.jpg to file3.jpg
echo "file$((RANDOM % 4)).jpg"
```

Comment: You may want to post it as your own answer - it then could earn you reputation.

Comment: helpful use of `RANDOM`, I accepted!

Comment: Note that RANDOM % N doesn't result in an equal distribution unless the number of possible values of RANDOM (32768) is divisible by N. To see this, imagine the range of RANDOM was instead 0-4 (5 possible values), and N is 2: there's three ways for $RANDOM % 2 to yield 0 (if $RANDOM yields 0, 2, 4) but two ways for it to yield 1 (1, 3). For an equal distribution you'd have to find the greatest multiple of N that's smaller than 32767 and ignore any random values that are larger than that. In the previous example that'd amount to ignoring 5, which is larger than 4.

Comment: @Doval I said that in my answer, did you see it?

Comment: @neon_overload My bad, I missed that bit.

Answer (score 8):

According to @neon_overload answer (using `RANDOM`),
I can put `RANDOM` in example script as follows (for 4 commands):

```
#!/bin/bash
random_selection=$((RANDOM % 4))

case $random_selection in

  0)
  <command_1>
  ;;

  1)
  <command_2>
  ;;

  2)
  <command_3>
  ;;

  3)
  <command_4>
  ;;

esac
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want randomness through an external site rather than one generated by your computer, you can use this script:

```
curl "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=$1&max=$2&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"
```

Run as rand (MIN) (MAX) (assuming you save as /usr/bin/rand)

You might have to install curl first (sudo apt-get install curl) if it is not already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`shuf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/shuf.1.html)** command from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

```
NAME
       shuf - generate random permutations

SYNOPSIS
       shuf [OPTION]... [FILE]
       shuf -e [OPTION]... [ARG]...
       shuf -i LO-HI [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Write a random permutation of the input lines to standard output
```

Example:

```
$ shuf -i 1-5
4
1
2
5
3
```

```
$ shuf -e Debian Ubuntu Trisquel 
Trisquel
Debian
Ubuntu
```

Now, For getting one random entry you can use `-n 1` which outputs first line.

Example for printing random number from 1-100:

```
$ shuf -i 1-100 -n 1
37
```

If you've `file` with following contents:

```
$ cat file
command-1
command-2
command-3
command-4
command-5
```

You can also do something like:

```
$ shuf file -n 1
command-3
```