# How to display a random line from a text file?

Tags: scripts, text-processing

I am trying to write a shell script. The idea is to select a single line at random from text file and display it as an Ubuntu desktop notification.

But I want different lines to be selected each time I execute the script. Is there any solution to do this? I don't want the entire script. Just that simple thing only.

Comment: Also visit : http://askubuntu.com/q/492572/256099

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `shuf` utility to print random lines from file

```
$ shuf -n 1 filename
```

`-n` : number of lines to print

Examples:

```
$ shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd

git:x:998:998:git daemon user:/:/bin/bash

$ shuf -n 2 /etc/passwd

avahi:x:84:84:avahi:/:/bin/false
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/bin/false
```

Comment: But by using this, I have to change the value of n manually right? I want that shell to automatically chose another line in random. Not exactly needed to be in random. But some other line.

Comment: @AnanduMDas No you don't have to `n` denotes the number of lines to print. (ie whether you want only one line or two line). Not the line number(ie first line 2nd line).

Comment: @AnanduMDas: I have added some examples to my answer. Hope its clear now.

Comment: Thank u its clear now :)
I also found another algorithm,its like, store the current time(second only, by `date +%S` ) into a variable x, and then select that xth line using the `head` and `tail` commands from the text file. Anyway your method is more easier. Thanks

Comment: +1: `shuf` is in coreutils so it is available by default. Note: it loads the input file into memory. [There is an efficient algorithm that doesn't require it](http://askubuntu.com/a/527778/3712).

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `sort` command to get random line from the file.

```
sort -R filename | head -n1
```

Comment: note: `sort -R` produces different result than [`shuf -n1`](http://askubuntu.com/a/525601/3712) or [`select-random`](http://askubuntu.com/a/527778/3712) if there are duplicate lines in the input. See [@EliahKagan's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525599/how-to-display-a-random-line-from-a-text-file/525624#comment719930_525624).

Comment: I think that could be solved with `sort -uR`

Comment: Works on Mac too (where `shuf` is not installed by default)

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun, here is a **pure bash solution** which doesn't use `shuf`, `sort`, `wc`, `sed`, `head`, `tail` or any other external tools.

The only advantage over the `shuf` variant is that it's slightly faster, since it's pure bash. On my machine, for a file of 1000 lines the `shuf` variant takes about 0.1 seconds, while the following script takes about 0.01 seconds ;) So while `shuf` is the easiest and shortest variant, this is faster.

In all honesty I would still go for the `shuf` solution, unless high efficiency is an important concern.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=file.txt

# get line count for $FILE (simulate 'wc -l')
lc=0
while read -r line; do
 ((lc++))
done < $FILE

# get a random number between 1 and $lc
rnd=$RANDOM
let "rnd %= $lc"
((rnd++))

# traverse file and find line number $rnd
i=0
while read -r line; do
 ((i++))
 [ $i -eq $rnd ] && break
done < $FILE

# output random line
printf '%s\n' "$line"
```

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for the suggestions and good points. I'll admit there are quite a few corner cases I hadn't really given too much thought to. I wrote this really more for the fun of it. Using `shuf` is much better anyway. Thinking of it, I don't believe that pure bash is actually more efficient than using `shuf`, as I previously wrote. There may be the tiniest (constant) overhead when firing up an external tool, but then it will run mach faster than interpreted bash. So `shuf` certainly scales better. So let's say the script serves an educational purpose: It's nice to see it can be done ;)

Comment: GNU/Linux/Un*x has a lot of very well road-tested wheels I wouldn't want to re-invent, not unless it was a purely academic exercise. The "shell" was intended to be used to assemble lots of little existing parts that could be (re-)assembled in various ways via input/output & plenty o' options. Anything else is bad form, unless it's for sport (e.g, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour), in which case, play on...!

Comment: @michael_n Yes, I fully agree -- indeed, that's one of the things I tried to bring across in my last comment. Actually, I wrote pretty much the same: "for the fun of it" meaning "it's for sport", and "the script serves an educational purpose" meaning "it was a purely academic exercise" ;-)

Comment: @michael_n Though a "pure bash" way is mainly useful for teaching and to modify for other tasks, this is a more reasonable "for real" implementation than it may seem. Bash is widely available, but `shuf`'s GNU Coreutils – specific (e.g., not in FreeBSD 10.0). `sort -R` is portable, but solves a different (related) problem: strings appearing as multiple lines have probability equal to those appearing only once. (Of course, `wc` and other utilities could still be used.) I think the main limitation here is this never picks anything after the 32768th line (and becomes less random somewhat sooner).

Comment: Note: [`$RANDOM % n` may skew your random distribution even if `$RANDOM` itself is ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/generate-random-number#comment36748687_1195035)

Comment: @EliahKagan: How is `sort -R`  different? E.g., even if `a` lines occur twice as much as any other line: `for i in \`seq 1000000\`; do echo -e 'a\nc\na\nb\n' | sort -R | head -n1 ; done |
 python -c'from collections import Counter; import sys; print(Counter(sys.stdin))'` the result does *not* show skew: 
`Counter({'\n': 250559, 'a\n': 250100, 'c\n': 249726, 'b\n': 249615})`

Comment: EliahKagan and @J.F.Sebastian, you two got me thinking about how to implement a good PRNG in bash. I posted another question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527900/how-to-efficiently-generate-large-uniformly-distributed-random-integers-in-bas, maybe you have a good idea?

Comment: Malte Skoruppa: I see you've moved [the bash PRNG question to U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157250). Cool. Hint: `$((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM))` is in 0..2^30-1. @J.F.Sebastian It's `shuf`, not `sort -R`, that skews toward more frequent inputs. Put `shuf -n 1` in place of `sort -R | head -n1` and compare. (Btw 10^3 iterations is quicker than 10^6 and still quite enough to show the difference.) See also [a rougher, more visual demo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8418343/) and [this bit of silliness showing it works on big inputs where all strings are high frequency](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8418402/).

Comment: @EliahKagan Thank you for adding the U&L link. That `$((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM))` is a neat idea. It overcomes the "small range" limitation of normal `$RANDOM`. It does not overcome (by itself) the "bias" limitation when modulo'ed. Maybe by using a loop instead of a modulo? At any rate, if you want to post that as an answer to my question on U&L, it would complement the other ideas there nicely :)

Comment: @EliahKagan: `RANDOM`-based prng for 0..2^32-1 fails [dieharder](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dieharder.1.html) tests: `while echo $(( RANDOM << 17 | RANDOM << 2 | RANDOM >> 13 )); do :; done | perl -ne 'print pack "I>"' | dieharder -a -g 200`. I also tried to use lower bits `(RANDOM & 3)` instead of `(RANDOM >> 13)` (higher bits). I'm not optimistic about `$((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM))` for 0..2^30-1 range.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian In that command, the input to `dieharder` seems to be all zeros. Assuming this is not merely some strange mistake on my part, that certainly would explain why it's not random! Do you get good-looking data if you run `while echo $(( RANDOM << 17 | RANDOM << 2 | RANDOM >> 13 )); do :; done | perl -ne 'print pack "I>"' > out` for a while and then examine the contents of `out` with a hex editor? (Or view it however else you like.) I get all zeros, and `RANDOM` isn't the culprit: I get all zeros when I replace `$(( RANDOM << 17 | RANDOM << 2 | RANDOM >> 13 ))` with `100`, too.

Comment: @EliahKagan: you are right `,$_` is missing at the end in the perl command. I might have checked it with `,$_` and edited it out later. Another way to check for zeros is to pipe to hexdump: `| hd` instead of `> out`. diehard_birthdays test is passed with `while echo $(( RANDOM << 17 | RANDOM << 2 | RANDOM >> 13 )); do :; done | perl -ne 'print pack "I>",$_' | dieharder -a -g 200` command

Comment: @EliahKagan I implemented a solution in pure bash to generate large random numbers using your idea of concatenating bistrings resulting from repeated invocations of `$RANDOM`. [See my answer at U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157837). This solves the limitation you mentioned earlier, that a single invocation of `$RANDOM` never picks anything after the 32768th line. And it's still pure bash :-)

Comment: @EliahKagan: `$(( RANDOM <<15 | RANDOM ))` (30bit generator) fails the `dieharder` tests for some reason. See [`make test-file` test](https://github.com/zed/test-dieharder-bash-random).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Does the 15-bit test fail too? Also, what happens when you don't explicitly seed `RANDOM`? I'm not sure how `bash` gets its seed when you don't, but I suspect it's--at least sometimes--somewhat robust. Of course, I realize its output should look statistically random for nearly any seed value.

Comment: @EliahKagan: 15-bit fails too. It seems failing dieharder tests accept only 32bit input.

Answer (score 5):

Say you have file `notifications.txt`. We need to count total number of lines, to determine range of random generator:

```
$ cat notifications.txt | wc -l
```

Lets write to variable:

```
$ LINES=$(cat notifications.txt | wc -l)
```

Now to generate number from `0` to `$LINE` we will use `RANDOM` variable.

```
$ echo $[ $RANDOM % LINES]
```

Lets write it to variable:

```
$  R_LINE=$(($RANDOM % LINES))
```

Now we only need to print this line number:

```
$ sed -n "${R_LINE}p" notifications.txt
```

---

About RANDOM:

```
   RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between
          0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may be
          initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If RANDOM is unset,
          it  loses  its  special  properties,  even if it is subsequently
          reset.
```

Be sure your file have less then 32767 line numbers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/generate-random-number) if you need bigger random generator that works out of the box.

Example:

```
$ od -A n -t d -N 3 /dev/urandom | tr -d ' '
```

Comment: A stylistic alternative (bash): `LINES=$(wc -l < file.txt); R_LINE=$((RANDOM % LINES)); sed -n "${R_LINE}p" file.txt`

Comment: Note: [`$RANDOM % n` may skew your random distribution even if `$RANDOM` itself is ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/generate-random-number#comment36748687_1195035)

Comment: e.g., look at the last picture in [Test PRNG using gray bitmap](https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/jfs/Test%20PRNG%20using%20gray%20bitmap) to understand why it is not a good idea to apply `% n` to a random number.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Python script that selects a random line from input files or stdin:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Usage: select-random [<file>]..."""
import random

def select_random(iterable, default=None, random=random):
    """Select a random element from iterable.

    Return default if iterable is empty.
    If iterable is a sequence then random.choice() is used for efficiency instead.
    If iterable is an iterator; it is exhausted.
    O(n)-time, O(1)-space algorithm.
    """
    try:
        return random.choice(iterable) # O(1) time and space
    except IndexError: # empty sequence
        return default
    except TypeError: # not a sequence
        return select_random_it(iter(iterable), default, random.randrange)

def select_random_it(iterator, default=None, randrange=random.randrange):
    """Return a random element from iterator.

    Return default if iterator is empty.
    iterator is exhausted.
    O(n)-time, O(1)-space algorithm.
    """
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456750/4279
    # select 1st item with probability 100% (if input is one item, return it)
    # select 2nd item with probability 50% (or 50% the selection stays the 1st)
    # select 3rd item with probability 33.(3)%
    # select nth item with probability 1/n
    selection = default
    for i, item in enumerate(iterator, start=1):
        if randrange(i) == 0: # random [0..i)
            selection = item
    return selection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import fileinput
    import sys

    random_line = select_random_it(fileinput.input(), '\n')
    sys.stdout.write(random_line)
    if not random_line.endswith('\n'):
        sys.stdout.write('\n') # always append newline at the end
```

The algorithm is O(n)-time, O(1)-space. It works for files larger than 32767 lines. It doesn't load input files into memory. It reads each input line exactly once i.e., you can pipe arbitrary large (but finite) content into it. Here's an [explanation of the algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933159/4279).

Answer (score 1):

I'm impressed by the work that Malte Skoruppa and others did, but here is a much simpler "pure bash" way to do it:

```
IFS=$'\012'
# set field separator to newline only
lines=( $(<test5) )
# slurp entire file into an array
numlines=${#lines[@]}
# count the array elements
num=$(( $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM % numlines ))
# get a (more-or-less) random number within the correct range
line=${lines[$num]}
# select the element corresponding to the random number
echo $line
# display it
```

As some have noted, $RANDOM is not random. However, the file size limit of 32767 lines is overcome by stringing $RANDOMs together as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{a[NR]=$0}END{x=int(rand()*NR)+1; print a[x]}' notifications.txt
```

Comment: It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
BEGIN { srand() }
1/NR >= rand() { line = $0 }
END { print line }'
```

Comment: Could you add some explanatory details to your answer?