# How can I generate a number start with 1 and only has 10 digit bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How can I generate all the numbers that start with 1 and have 10 digits?

For example:
start with:
1000000000
...
end with:
1999999999

And how to save the result in a text file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a random number within a range in command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213233/how-to-get-a-random-number-within-a-range-in-command-line)

Comment: Hi Artur Meinild, no start with number 1 only and have 10 digits

Comment: ... "start with number 1 only and have 10 digits" - sorry, this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: haha I mean for example : 1000000000 1100000000 ... 1111111111 , 1011111111 and end with 1999999999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

If you're looking to generate a random(-ish) number:

```bsh
num=1
for i in {1..9}; do num+=$((RANDOM % 10)); done
echo "$num" > text.file
```

If you want the billion numbers from 1,000,000,000 to 1,999,999,999

```bsh
for ((i = 1000000000; i <= 1999999999; i++)); do
    echo "$i"
done > text.file
```

As suggested by @bac0n

```sh
seq 1000000000 1999999999 > text.file
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want many thanks.

Comment: I'm still curious: _which_ did you want?

Comment: I wanted all numbers between 1000000000 to 19999999999. :)