# Random variable in bash

Tags: bash

Would you please help me to create a random variable within (p a t) range. I mean a command that will generate a random a variable within values p, a or t.

Thank you

Comment: do you mean a random variable in the range (p,a), uniformly distributed?  what is t?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get randomness in command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492572/how-do-i-get-randomness-in-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "variable" `$RANDOM` which is actually an internal Bash function (not a constant) that returns a *pseudorandom* integer in the range 0..32767. To convert this number to an integer in the range 0..2, you can multiply it by 3 and (integer) divide by 32768 (=32767+1).

```
# Set a string that will contain your characters:
str='pat'

# Calculate the number of characters in the string:
strlen=${#str}

# Get a random integer in the range 0..2 (0..strlen-1):
let r=RANDOM*strlen/32768

# Get one random character from the strlen-character string (str):
echo ${str:r:1}
```

---

Or you can use the [shuf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/shuf.1.html) command like this:

```
shuf -e -n1 'p' 'a' 't'
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash has the special `$RANDOM` variable that prints a random numerical value. You can calculate `$RANDOM` [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `3` to get a value between 0 and 2, which means that you can save your target values in an array and then pick a random element:

```
#!/bin/bash

## these are your p, a and t
values=(10 5 876)

## get a random value between 0 and 2
index=$((RANDOM % 3))

## print the corresponding element
echo ${values[$index]}
```

I ran this in a loop 1000 times and, as you can see below, I got each of the three values approximately a third of the times, as expected:

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do foo.sh ; done | sort | uniq -c
    364 10
    306 5
    330 876
```

That means the script printed `10` 364 times, `5` 306 times and `876` 330 times.